# Array filled with how frequently letters appeared in text file. How to sort (descending) in C and still know which letter went with which number?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, encryption

Totally a homework assignment and I've been stuck here for a couple days. Simple substitution cipher, encryption program works fine and I think I've got most of decryption figured out except this one part.

It creates an array of 26 int's (one for each letter) and loops through the text, increasing the appropriate index each time it encounters the associated letter. Right now the index is how I know what slot is what letter (a is [0], b is [1], c[2], etc).

How do I sort this array by size (so that I can tease apart frequencies) while still knowing what letter the number is associated with? (ie, 'a' appears 600 times, 'b' appears 30 times, 'c' appears 82 times, etc)

Comment: [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) may help.

Comment: You need to store structs, with char code and count fields. Then sort those. If you have not gone through structs yet, you could have two arrays, one for char codes and other for counts, and then when sorting you sort by the count array but do the swap on both arrays, so they stay in sync.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, sounds much cleaner. Out of curiosity, any clue on the downvotes? I always hesitate to post anything here (even when I've been stuck for awhile) because I can't figure out why people seem to disapprove of asking for help   Edit: grammar

Comment: ...wrote my comment as an answer, since I figured this is, after all, quite reasonable question, even if it is very basic. Still, it explains what you are doing and why and what your problem is. But the downvotes are probably because this is so basic a question, and many folks here are somewhat allergic to "homework" questions, with itchy downvote fingers.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the insight. I guess I should keep quiet until I (hopefully) make it into the workforce then. No sense in fostering negative rep in the mean time. As far as structs, this is my first time using C (Java and C++ previously so I guess I should've known better anyway). Took a look at them just now and holy cow they're simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store structs, with char code and count fields. Then sort those. Note that in C you can use structs like any variables, pass them around and assign them. You don't have to use pointers or something like that, unlike when you are dealing with arrays.

If you for some reason don't want to use structs (like, if you have not learned them yet...), you could have two arrays, one for char codes and other for counts, with same size. Then you do sorting by the count array, but do swap in both arrays, so they stay in sync.